# Google In app purchase return error code 6

Tags: java, android

onPurchasesUpdated unable to consumeAsync and billingResult result error code 6.

I have tried moving consumeAsync to queryPurchases and queryPurchaseHistoryAsync, and the purchase will only be consume in queryPurchaseHistoryAsync and not queryPurchases

```java
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                        && purchases != null) {
                    for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                        handlePurchase(purchase);
                        //The following consumeAsync not working, return error code 6
                        ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .setDeveloperPayload(purchase.getDeveloperPayload())
                                .build();
                        billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) {
//billingResult return code 6 here. 
                                Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(billingResult.getResponseCode()));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                    // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
                } else {
                    // Handle any other error codes.
                }
            }
        }).enablePendingPurchases().build();
```

consumeAsync not working under queryPurchases():

```java
Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                    for(Purchase purchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {
                        handlePurchase(purchase);
                        ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .setDeveloperPayload(purchase.getDeveloperPayload())
                                .build();
                        billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) { 
                                Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(billingResult.getResponseCode()));
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

consumeAsync only works under the following code (I understand that the method is wrong and the item will be consumed over and over again and return code 8, but it is the only way that the item will be consumed):

```java
     billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<PurchaseHistoryRecord> purchaseHistoryRecordList) {
                            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                                    && purchaseHistoryRecordList != null) {
                                for (PurchaseHistoryRecord purchase : purchaseHistoryRecordList) {
                                    handlePurchaseHistoryRecord(purchase);
                                    ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                            .setDeveloperPayload(purchase.getDeveloperPayload())
                                            .build();
                                    billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) { 
                                            Log.i("TAG", "item consumed");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Why are you trying to immediately consume every purchase?  Are you trying to do this for testing purposes, so you can repurchase?

Comment: Im sorry I thought it was supposed to be consumed immediately after purchase and grant item to user?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will consume every purchase as soon as it is made.  In general, you would only want to consume a managed product if you want the buyer to be able to repurchase that product again.  This might be the case if your item is expected to be consumable, such as additional coins in a game.  Once the coins run out, you would consume the purchase, then the buyer could purchase more coins.

Another scenario where you might consume a purchase would be for testing, where you might want to purchase a product multiple times.  You could set up a temporary button or other method to consume the purchase so that you can continue repurchasing while working out any bugs in your code.

A third scenario might be after you have issued a buyer a refund.  After the refund, you might want to consume the purchase to give the buyer an option to purchase the product again.

These are the only three scenarios I can think of off hand where you would want to consume a managed product.

**Edit**

To YKW's comment:
YKW made a good point about purchasing additional coins that didn't initially occur to me... but either way, you can't consume the product a second time until you get a valid consumption response back from the first purchase consumption and then the product is purchased again.  In this case, at a minimum you should first check to make sure the purchase is not PurchaseState.Pending.  Then consume the product, not allowing the product to be purchased again until you get the onConsume response back.  You will also want to check each time your app and/or activity starts and consume any purchased products as google confirms that occasionally a consumption will fail.

**End Edit**

**UPDATE**

Another possibility for receiving response code 6 is the developer payload string is empty.  You can remove the .setDeveloperPayload(purchase.getDeveloperPayload()) line as specifying a developer payload is optional for ConsumeParams.

If you want to send a developer payload, make sure that purchase.getDeveloperPayload() is not returning an empty string.

**END UPDATE**

There is a good example of a method for consuming a purchase in the trivial drive app.

[Trivial Drive V2 BillingManager](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/BillingManager.java)

Here is a method I use for debugging based on the one found in the trivial drive V2 app.

```
void consumeAsync(final ConsumeParams consumeParams) {
    // If we've already scheduled to consume this token - no action is needed (this could happen
    // if you received the token when querying purchases inside onReceive() and later from
    // onActivityResult()
    if (paramsSetToConsume == null) {
        paramsSetToConsume = new HashSet<>();
    } else if (paramsSetToConsume.contains(consumeParams)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Params was already scheduled to be consumed - skipping...");
        return;
    }
    paramsSetToConsume.add(consumeParams);

    // Generating Consume Response listener
    final ConsumeResponseListener onConsumeListener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) {
            // If billing service was disconnected, we try to reconnect 1 time
            // (feel free to introduce your retry policy here).
            Log.d(TAG, "ConsumeResponseListener fired.  sending to onConsumedFinished listener");
            mBillingUpdatesListener.onConsumeFinished(consumeParams.getPurchaseToken(), billingResult.getResponseCode());
        }
    };
// Creating a runnable from the request to use it inside our connection retry policy below
    Runnable consumeRequest = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Consume the purchase async
            Log.d(TAG, "consumeParams being sent to billingClient to consume");
            billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, onConsumeListener);
        }
    };

    executeServiceRequest(consumeRequest);
}
```

Then I set up a temporary button, create my ConsumeParams and call this method in the onClick listener.

paramsSetToConsume is a member variable

```
private Set<ConsumeParams> paramsSetToConsume;
```

Comment: `Once the coins run out, you would consume the purchase, then the buyer could purchase more coins.` What if the user wants to purchase for several times? For example, each purchase is 100 coins and they need 500 coins. In this case the purchase should be consumed immediately?

Comment: Im actually having trouble consuming the item still. onConsumeFinished will return error code 6.

Comment: Are you sure the purchase state indicates purchased before you are trying to consume it?  i.e. purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED.  Developer payload is optional for ConsumeParams.  Have you tried omitting the developer payload to see if maybe it is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, the status is showing PURCHASED. Consume only works when I queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(). It just won't work under queryPurchase and others consume situation..

Comment: What about the payload? Are you sending a payload along with the purchase?  If not,  you are sending an empty payload string to consumeAsync.  This could cause the error you are getting.  Try removing the .setDeveloperPayload line, since developerPayload is optional, or if you are going to send a payload, make sure the payload string is not empty.